# Reusable form elements AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm just starting to learn AngularJS (I have to use 1.6) and I want to make a some components to handle form fields to keep my templates neater and and limit the places I'll have to change something if I decide form fields should be/act different.

So far I've followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@pugillum/creating-a-custom-form-field-with-validation-using-angularjs-1-5-and-typescript-ece9c6c3168f) with a some twists. They don't have enough validation, so I wanted to be able to pass an array of strings to decide how the field should be validated (i.e. ['required', 'properCase', 'notTooLong'], where required would make sure it's not null, properCase would check if the first letter was capitalized and notTooLong would check if it was under 10 characters. Just random examples).

Similar to how `redux-form field level validation works`. [link](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/)

But the first problem I'm running into is how to pass an array? 
My `logOn.html` template looks like this...

```
<form name="compact-signin" novalidate class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <text-field placeHolder="Username" ng-model="user.username" [validations]="['required']"></text-field>
    <text-field type="password" placeHolder="Password" ng-model="user.password"></text-field>
</form>
```

and then I try and receive it in my `text-field-component` like so...

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import TextFieldController from './text-field.controller';

const template: string = require('./text-field.html');
const TextFieldComponent: angular.IComponentOptions = {
  template: template,
  controller: TextFieldController,
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  require: {
    model: 'ngModel'
  },
  bindings: {
    label: '@',
    placeholder: '@',
    type: '@',
    validations: '='
  }
};

export default TextFieldComponent;
```

Except in the controller, it is always undefined.

The next problem is, should I really be handling validation like that? I'm kind of confused if that should be in a controller (like it is) or in a directive?

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@pugillum/creating-a-custom-form-field-with-validation-using-angularjs-1-5-and-typescript-ece9c6c3168f)

Comment: @Korte thanks, but that's the same one I linked

Comment: No it's not :/ ?

Comment: Haha I have two links in there, one to the tutorial I followed (same link you posted) and one to redux forms to explain what I was trying to do